# Change the style of a single element within an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-ng-repeat, mouseover, mouseleave

I have angular code that has a number of different time segments per week. They are all within an ng-repeat. I want to be able to change the colour of a time segment whenever the mouse is over that item. With my current code the colour gets changes for every item within the ng-repeat.

```js
public onSegmentMouseOverLeave(changeSegmentColor : boolean) : void {
        this.timeSegmentColor = changeSegmentColor;
    }
```

```css
        .time-segment-grid {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          margin-top: 2px;
          height: 35px;
          border-radius: 5px;
          cursor: pointer;
          z-index: 1;
          #gradient > .vertical(#1b9dd0, #0080b5);
        }
        .time-segment-grid-onmove {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          margin-top: 2px;
          height: 35px;
          border-radius: 5px;
          cursor: pointer;
          z-index: 1;
          #gradient > .vertical(#f442d7, #0080b5);
        }
```

```html
<div>
 <div ng-repeat="timeSegment in $ctrl.deal.deal_settings.dayparting.schedule[dayName] track by $index">

  <span ng-class="$ctrl.daypartingTimeSegments.timeSegmentColor ? 'time-segment-grid' : 'time-segment-grid-onmove'  "
        ng-style="$ctrl.daypartingTimeSegments.timeSegmentGridStyle(timeSegment)"
        ng-mousedown="$ctrl.daypartingTimeSegments.onSegmentDragStart($event, dayName, $index, 'dragFullContent')"
        ng-mouseover="$ctrl.daypartingTimeSegments.onSegmentMouseOverLeave(false)"
        ng-mouseleave="$ctrl.daypartingTimeSegments.onSegmentMouseOverLeave(true)">
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkIlY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your HTML, I would do:

```
ng-mouseover="mouseOverOn = true"
ng-mouseleave="mouseOverOn = false"
ng-class="{hoverstyle: mouseOverOn}"
```

Which would correspond to the CSS class hoverstyle.

Right now, your code is evaluating an expression that has no correlation to the element within ng-repeat, which is why they are all highlighting.

If you need the other expressions, you can add to the expression:

```
ng-mouseover="mouseOverOn = true; $ctrl.daypartingTimeSegments.onSegmentMouseOverLeave(false)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why using code when CSS can support it =(

```
    .time-segment-grid {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      margin-top: 2px;
      height: 35px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
      z-index: 1;
      #gradient > .vertical(#1b9dd0, #0080b5);
    }
    .time-segment-grid:hover {
      #gradient > .vertical(#f442d7, #0080b5);
    }
```